# Dynamic slot name in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've faced an issue with dynamic slot names and index.

This doesn't work:

```js
<template v-for="(item, i) in items" #[headers[i].value]>
  INDEX: {{ i }}
</template>
```

it cannot read `i` index, but if i use static index, it does work:

```js
<template v-for="(item, i) in items" #[headers[0].value]>
  INDEX: {{ i }}
</template>
```

**headers** is a computed function:

```js
const headers = computed(() => {
  const arr = []

  if (props.schema?.fields?.length) {
    props.schema.fields.forEach(field => {
      arr.push({
        text: field.name,
        value: field.value,
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. Also, are you sure that your `items` are properly populated when this code is run? Template is sync, if you don't have the data populated in the beginning it may error. [This](https://twitter.com/kissu_io/status/1457436910754877442/photo/1) works fine so you should be close.

Comment: [Looks just fine to me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-mjaefq?file=src/App.vue). But in your code, indexing `headers` with `i` (which is index from `items`) looks strange and can be dangerous. Are you sure those two arrays have same number of elements?

Comment: @MichalLevý it must be the same number of elements. Probably i just have to merge these headers values in to the items. But still, why it doesn't work this way? Any ideas?

Comment: How doesn't work? It works. Check my demo. Only time it was failing was when I had two different arrays - `items` **and** `headers` like you do - and first one was bigger. My guess is it is the array size problem you have